# Combining and returning arrays from Model to Controller - CodeIgniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to combine two arrays from two separate queries. I stored my products in two separate tables: one for general information like name, description, price, etc; and another for their various details i.e. a clothing items size and colour.

So my database is structured like this for products:

```
products table:
p_id | title | descr | etc

product_attrs table:
attr_id | products.p_id | name | value
```

where name and value can be name = Size value = Large

If I trying getting all the details for a product out in one query, like this:

```
this->db->select('products.title,
                           p.description,
                           p.price,
                           p.stock,
                           p.name,
                           p.value');
        $this->db->from('p');
        $this->db->where('p.p_id', $id);
        $this->db->join('product_attrs', 'product_attrs.product_id = p.p_id', 'inner');
        $result = $this->db->get();

        return $result->result_array();
```

I get an array populated with the number of name/value pairs there are in the table product_attributes for that product. So if there are say 5 attributes of a product, I would get everything back 5 times like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 [name] => Brand [value] => Modestly Active Swimwear ) [1] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 [name] => Colour [value] => Black and Light Blue ) [2] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 [name] => size [value] => small ) [3] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 [name] => size [value] => medium ) [4] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 [name] => size [value] => large ) )
```

So I decided to separate the queries for each table, so that I can get one result set each. But I want to combine them both so that I can return the data back as one array to the Controller and display that onto my view. This is how I've queried the two tables, I just need a way to combine the results for both:

```
$this->db->select('p.title,
                           p.description,
                           p.price,
                           p.stock');
        $this->db->from('p');
        $this->db->where('p_id', $id);
        $result = $this->db->get();

        $this->db->select('name, value');
        $this->db->from('product_attrs');
        $this->db->where('p_id', $id);
        $result2 = $this->db->get();
```

If someone could please help I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you

EDIT:

I'm looking at array_merge() function right now in php.net, but if I do this:

```
$result = $this->db->get();
        $array1 = $result->result_array();

$result2 = $this->db->get();
        $array2 = $result2->result_array();
        $data = array_merge($array1,$array2);
        return $data;
```

I get more than one array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [title] => Modest Swimsuit - Full body [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant [price] => 59.95 [stock] => 20 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Brand [value] => Modestly Active Swimwear ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Colour [value] => Black and Light Blue ) [3] => Array ( [name] => size [value] => small ) [4] => Array ( [name] => size [value] => medium ) [5] => Array ( [name] => size [value] => large ) )
```

Is there a way to get the values out of the above array in my view?

Comment: I think I've got it. I use the function array_merge(), and then in my view I can get the values out like: echo $product_details[0]['title'];. Thank God for var_dump!

Comment: OP trying to edit answer: the former name of the table is VERY generic so I don't see any problem. And you didn't edit all the occurences is it? You edited your question, well whatever but you still have `.description` in question and try to edit the answer to `.desc`. Wouldn't match anymore.

Comment: @FelipeAls I thought that was the point :/ . Is being generic a good thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative would be to loop through the second results array and add the values to the first array.

```
    // Get products results as an array
    $this->db->select('products.title,
                       products.description,
                       products.price,
                       products.stock');
    $this->db->from('products');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
    $product = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    // Get product attributes as an array
    $this->db->select('name, value');
    $this->db->from('product_attributes');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $id);
    $product_attributes = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    // Loop through the results
    foreach($product_attributes as $attribute) {

         // Add results to original product array
         $product[$attribute['name']] = $attribute['value'];
    }
```

This should produce an array like this:

```
        [title]       => Modest Swimsuit - Full body 
        [description] => UV +50 Protection - Chlorine Resistant - Water Resistant - Quick Drying - Maximum Breathe Ability- Sea Water Resistant 
        [price]       => 59.95 
        [stock]       => 20
        [Brand]       => Modestly Active Swimwear 
        [Colour]      => Black and Light Blue
        [size]        => small
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner result, I'll try it out. Thanks for your help :)